# Problema con el uso de caracteres especiales en la clave secreta usando AES

Tags: c#, seguridad, cifrado

Uso AES para encriptar datos en una aplicación web. Todo me funciona correctamente cuando la clave secreta no contiene caracteres especiales. Si añado alguno me funciona el encriptado pero no el desencriptado.
Me gustaría saber si la clave secreta de 128 bits de 16 caracteres  que empleo permite el uso de caracteres especiales o en cambio solo caracteres alfanuméricos. No logro aclararme con la documentación de Microsoft. Según leo la propiedad *Key* es un valor de  tipo *byte[]*. Si la longitud de la clave en mi caso es de 16 caracteres, se trata de una matriz de 16 bytes (128 bits). Pero no he encontrado donde especifiquen si esos bytes tienen que ser caracteres alfanuméricos, especiales, etc.

La función *Ca* devuelve un string resultado de la operación de encriptado (E) o de desencriptado (D). Dependiendo del tipo de operación se emplea la función de encriptado o de desencriptado. En ningún caso me da problemas el encriptado, pero el desencriptado falla cuando añado un carácter especial a la clave secreta. Esta clave secreta es una cadena de 16 caracteres establecida como valor de sesión al cargarse la aplicación.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public string Ca(string texto, string operacion)
            //Cifrado Aes (Ca)
        {
            string base64;

            using (Aes myAes = Aes .Create())
            {
                myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
     
                byte[] key_aes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["key_AES"]));

                if (key_aes == null || key_aes.Length == 0)
                {
                    goto salida;
                }
                if (operacion == "E")
                {
                    // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
                    byte[] encriptado = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(texto, key_aes, key_aes);
                    //Convertimos en un string 
                   base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(encriptado);
                    return base64;                 

                }
                else if (operacion == "D")
                {
                    byte[] bytedesdeCampo = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(texto);
                    // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
                    try
                    {
                        string desencriptado = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(bytedesdeCampo, key_aes, key_aes);
                        return desencriptado;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {  //este error se produce cuando la key no es correcta (EL relleno entre caracteres no es admitido y no se puede quitar)
                        string asdfads = e.Message;
                        if (e.Message.Contains("Longitud no válida"))
                        {

                        }
                        return texto;
                    }
                }
                salida:
                return "";
            }
        }
        static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            if (plainText.Length == 0)
            {
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("");
            }
            if (Key == null)
            {
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("");
            }
            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted;

            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;
        }

        static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
            
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return plaintext;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado.

He cambiado

```
byte[] bytedesdeCampo = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(texto);
```

por

```
byte[] bytedesdeCampo = Convert.FromBase64String(texto);
```

El método *Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes* estaba produciendo el problema al no poder convertir implicitamente un string en byte[]. Sin embargo el método *Convert.FromBase64String* devuelve el byte[] correctamente.
Ahora puedo usar en la Key de AES los caracteres especiales sin que dé error tanto al encriptar como al desencriptar.

Además he comprobado que no todas las combinaciones de caracteres especiales ni todos los caracteres especiales son admitidos. Cuando ocurre que no lo son en el método *Convert.FromBase64String* se producirá el error de que la longitud de la matriz de bytes o la cadena de Base 64 no es válida.
Al menos los siguientes caracteres especiales son admitidos en la clave secreta (además de los alfanuméricos):

```
@*&<,-:;><(?=._;
```

Cuando se repiten se producen errores, y si aparecen tres o más veces siempre se produce el error. Con el carácter * repetido hasta cuatro veces no he tenido problemas.